# In JPA is it possible to map custom results which has joins

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities `Student` and `AppliedCourses`

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private Long sid;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    .
    .
    .
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sid", referencedColumnName = "sid")
    private Set<AppliedCourses> appliedCourses;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class AppliedCourses {
    @Id
    private Long apcid;
    private Long sid;
    private String courseName;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

jpql query to fetch student entity with applied courses is :

```
select s from Student s left join fetch s.appliedCourses ac where s.id=:sid
```

but the requirement is that i want to select only few columns in Student along with applied courses set

ie, i want something like this :

```
select new com.foo.StudentStat(s.sid, s.name, s.appliedCourses) 
from Student s left join fetch s.appliedCourses ac where s.sid=:sid
```

StudentStat result class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentStat {
    private Long sid;
    private String name;
    private Set<AppliedCourses> appliedCourses;
}
```

The above query throws following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

Is there any other way in which i can achieve this requirement ?

Comment: you cannot use a MULTI-VALUED field in the constructor expression

Comment: Is there any other way that we can achieve this in jpa? or should i split them into 2 queries ? @Neil

Comment: you could do as a single query, return s.name and ac.* and then put all back together in the structure you require in user code perhaps

Comment: Actually I want to avoid few columns which have high memory.

Comment: I am doing this to reduce fetch time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JPA 2.1 specification (JSR 338) does not allow referencing a collection resulting from a fetch join if the owning entity is not itself returned in the query result:

JSR 338, section 4.4.5.3:

> The association referenced by the right side of the FETCH JOIN clause **must be an association or element collection that is referenced from an entity or embeddable that is returned as a result of the query**. It is not permitted to specify an identification variable for the objects referenced by the right side of the FETCH JOIN clause, and hence references to the implicitly fetched entities or elements cannot appear elsewhere in the query.

An alternative might be to define an [`EntityGraph`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm) but is probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
List resultWithAliasedBean = s.createQuery("select s.sid, s.name, s.appliedCourses from Student s left join fetch s.appliedCourses ac where s.sid=:sid").setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(StudentStat.class)).list();
StudentStat pojo = (StudentStat) resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);
```

// If you are using criteria you can use to transform the result.

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(StudentStat.class));
```

Comment: s.createQuery().setResultTransformer is this hibernate specific ?

Comment: yes its session.createQuery().setResultTransformer. there must be alternative in JPA for creating JPQL.

Comment: The important thing is Transformers.aliasToBean(StudentStat.class)